# Is left dimension preserved by left translation?

Tags: dimension-theory, division-rings

Let ${\bf K}\supset K\supset L$ be division rings with $[K:L]_{\rm left}=\infty$, and $a\in {\bf K}^\times$.

> **Question.** Is it possible that $[aK:L]_{\rm left}<\infty$ in the sense that there would be no infinitely many members of $aK$ that are left $L$-free?